# coordinate conversion script isn't giving me an accurate reading SVY21 to WGS84

Tags: python, c++, google-maps, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I would like to convert my dataset of SVY21 coordinates, into WGS84 coordinates.

I am currently using this script from this repo I found but [this script](https://github.com/cgcai/SVY21) this yields inaccurate results with a discrepancy of up to 0.04, so the coordinates that I convert end up being on an entirely different geographical location in the same country.

Was wondering if there is anyone who can assist to help me with a script for converting a large dataset from SVY21 to WGS84?

E.G I want to convert

```
38816.0396118, 34379.9602051
```

but instead I get

```
1.36728713070321, 103.890645888016
```

when I should be getting

```
1.327235496598071, 103.93042021823591
```

I would do it on those online converters but my file sizes are pretty big(can go up to few GB) so it's better to run a script on my local computer instead using either Python or C++ or any other alternatives that will work. Also most online converters have a limit on file size as well.

Here's an accurate converter link: https://dominoc925-pages.appspot.com/webapp/calc_svy21/default.html but it doesnt accept my file size.

Appreciate the help :D Thanks~!

Comment: This might be a better fit for gis.stackexchange.com. Having said that: .04 degrees corresponds to about 4 km at the equator which, incidentally, is about the difference between your X and Y coordinates. Are you sure you haven't flipped them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have your coordinates the wrong way around. Consider the following:

```
import pyproj

xfm = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs('EPSG:3414', 'EPSG:4326')
x, y = 38816.0396118, 34379.9602051

print(xfm.transform(x, y))
# prints: (1.3673123058118237, 103.89064694097199)

print(xfm.transform(y, x))
# prints: (1.3271927478890677, 103.93050656742128)
```

Still about a ten-thousandth of a degree off, but I don't know how good pyproj's coordinate space definitions are in this case.